# Get Custom Web template name programmatically , Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-template

I am trying to get the web template name that is being used currently in order to create the site.

I have created and `EvenReceiver` and overriding `WebProvisioned`. in this method i would like to get the name of the template i am currently using in order to create the subsite.

I am using code below. `GetCustomWebTemplates` and `GetWebTemplates` gives list of all the templates but i am only interested in getting the name of the current one. Is it possible? any idea how can we do that? Kindly help.

```
using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(properties.FullUrl))
        {
            SPWeb thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();

            SPWebTemplateCollection stc = thisSite.GetWebTemplates(thisWeb.Language);
            foreach (SPWebTemplate sc in stc)
            {
                string MyTempleName = sc.Name;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SPWeb.WebTemplate` to get the name of the template.

```
using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(properties.FullUrl))
        {
            SPWeb thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();

            string MyTempleName = thisWeb.WebTemplate ;

        }
```

Comment: Just a question before i try it out. Does it work with custom templates(created using VS) as well?

Comment: Yes, it should work.